# permission denied when writing to mounted directory exported by NFS server running on OpenBSD OS

Tags: permissions, nfs, mount, openbsd

I have a default installation of openbsd, with portmap, mountd, nfsd services started by via rcctl. I have following entry in /etc/exports

```
/nfs/testdir -alldirs  -maproot=root -network=192.168.0 -mask=255.255.255.0
```

I am able to mount the exported share on client as follows:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o rw,noauto -v 192.168.0.122:/nfs/testdir mntpt3
```

From the client, I can read the contents.But writing inside the mounted directory yields permission denied error.
Looking at the docs I am not able to find any other config options for access control on the client side.
There is nothing in the logs in server side as well
Any potential ideas to would be of great help.

### Thanks